# Ionic Contacts plugin not saving contact on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, plugins, contacts

I'm facing a problem when I try to save a contact on Android. It works fine on iOS, but when I try it on Android the app crashes closing itself.

I'm using Ionic 3 and Ionic Native Contacts interface. The plugin is https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts. I know it says it's deprecated, but I can't find another trusty plugin.

The troublesome code is the save method:

```js
let contact: Contact = this.contacts.create();

contact.name = new ContactName(null, 'Smith', 'John');
contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField('mobile', '6471234567')];
contact.save().then(
  () => console.log('Contact saved!', contact),
  (error: any) => console.error('Error saving contact.', error)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a post that has an explanation on this issue, basically you need to replace `ContactManager.java` file in the contacts plugin that asks for read/write permission, then remove android platform and re add it.

[This is the updated ContactManager.java](https://github.com/duncan-c/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/master/src/android/ContactManager.java)

After updating the file at `plugins/cordova-plugin-contacts/src/android/ContactManager.java` with the updated version, you have to run:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android
```

[Here is the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52730546/1303897)